# How to position reCAPTCHA popup fit inside the mobile screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, recaptcha

I need to debug an application and the issue is that the reCAPTCHA window the one where you have to select several images from the same kind is placed a little bit strange meaning that the Verify button is not in the visible screen which means that I can not move further from that page since I can not validate the options that I have picked.

Html wise, it's because that the div container has a top position a little bit more that it should be and it pusshes the popup outside the screen direction down.

I have checked the [reCAPTCHA documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3) but there is little to none mention of how to position the popup. From here I guess that it should automatically position it self the right way but in my case it definitely does not.

I mention that this happens only on small screens like Iphone SE, but for Iphone 12 it works fine. I also mention that there is space left to drag the popup up in order to see the Verify button which is placed at the bottom of the popup.

How should I approach this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

There's two method to fix this problem. You can use `position:fixed;` or `max-height`:

**Position Fixed**

```js
// Position the reCAPTCHA window relative to the viewport.
var recaptchaWindow = document.getElementById('recaptcha-window');
recaptchaWindow.style.position = 'fixed';
recaptchaWindow.style.top = '0';
recaptchaWindow.style.left = '0';
```

```html
<div id="recaptcha-window" class="recaptcha-window">
  <div class="recaptcha-content">
    <div class="recaptcha-image"></div>
    <div class="recaptcha-buttons">
      <button class="recaptcha-verify">Verify</button>
      <button class="recaptcha-close">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Max Height**

```html
<div id="recaptcha-window" class="recaptcha-window" style="max-height: 300px;">
  <div class="recaptcha-content">
    <div class="recaptcha-image"></div>
    <div class="recaptcha-buttons">
      <button class="recaptcha-verify">Verify</button>
      <button class="recaptcha-close">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```